# OSGI plugin development with Domino Designer 10

Tags: osgi, xpages, domino-designer-eclipse

Up to date I was using IBM Domino Designer V9.0.1 FP8 to develop an OSGI plugin. With this version everything was working as intended. I've created a plugin project, a feature project and an update site project. Selecting "Build all" in the update site project created all the the corresponding jar files.

Today I've installed IBM (HCL) Domino Desinger V10 FP2 (fresh install i.e. I've deinstalled V9.0.1 and deleted the old "workspace" directory in NotesData, but I kept the NotesData itself).
Now if I open my plugin projects, I can edit the plugin, save the Java classes without any errors. Up to this point everything is working as usual. But now, if I use "Build all" in the update site project I see a screen with "generating ant script" and then the build process is finished, but no jar files are generated.
Any ideas why this is happening? Am I missing some files? Am I missing some configurations?

BTW: if I use standard eclipse to build the plugin all jar files are generated.

Comment: Do you have a *log.zip* file in your update site?

Comment: No, there's no _log.zip_ in the update site. Should there be one?

Comment: That's ok. The *log.zip* contains messages / errors when building a plugin. No log = no errors

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Domino Designer is a customised version of Eclipse. 9.0.1 FP9 and lower is a very old version of Eclipse, 9.0.1 FP10+ is a much newer version, so not comparable to what was happening before. It's possible there are differences in the customisation of Eclipse that are affecting it. But every Domino OSGi plugin developer I'm aware of uses standard Eclipse.

Follow the steps for setting up your environment here https://github.com/OpenNTF/XPagesExtensionLibrary/wiki/Development-Environment. In the documentation there I've tried to document why steps are done and what they achieve, as well as just the steps themselves. The intention is to pass on understanding to a broader set of developers, for future proofing.

Comment: Thanx Paul, I followed your instructions for setting up my environment and I'm using right now Eclipse for OSGI Development.